# Значение синтаксиса. Как компилятор воспринимает данный фрагмент кода?

Tags: c#

Работая с классом DataGridView, в одном коде встретил данный синтаксис, например, при объявлении  функции :

```
void Foo(DataGridView^ table_name)
```

Вопрос именно про знак "^". Что он обозначает, какой смысл несёт в себе? 
table_name здесь - это имя, присвоенное параметру - переменной (?)

Comment: Это что, C# или C++?

Comment: C#, "управляемый" код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `C#` нет такого синтаксиса. Скорее всего, речь идет про `C++/CLI`. В нем такой синтаксис используется для объявления указателя на управляемый объект.

Чтобы в `C++/CLI` объявить указатель на объект, используется конструкция с `^`:

```
ManagedType^ objPtr = gcnew ManagedType;
```

Чтобы создать ссылку на объект по указателю, используется `%`:

```
ManagedType% objRef = *objPtr;
```

Больше можно найти здесь: [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)